# Applications not installing due to unmet dependencies

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apt, dependencies

I was running Apache on Linode. I recently shifted to Lighttpd and removed apache, now whenever I try to install any application I get the following error.

```
    ivineet:~# apt-get install subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libapache2-mod-php5: Depends: apache2-mpm-prefork (> 2.0.52) but it is not going to be installed or
                                apache2-mpm-itk but it is not going to be installed
  subversion: Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.6.12dfsg-6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ivineet:~#
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the dependencies, then trying to install the package again?

Comment: The dependencies are related to Apache and I don't wont to install Apache again

Answer (score 1):

As the output suggests it, try to execute `apt-get -f install` in order to solve the dependency problem. As soon as it is fixed, installing the subversion package again should be working.

Comment: I got this
`(Reading database ... 18773 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libapache2-mod-php5 ...
touch: cannot touch `/etc/php5/apache2/.start': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--remove):
 subprocess pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Try creating the folder `/etc/php5/apache2` manually using `mkdir -p /etc/php5/apache2` and execute `apt-get -f install` again. Have you removed this folder manually before removing the package `libapache2-mod-php5`? If you have removed the apache folders manually, you will probably have to repeat this operation until dpkg can cleanly remove the package.